# Efficient queue clearing in C#

Tags: c#, queue, ram

I'm currently dealing with a queue that has a couple thousand entries in it. To save on RAM usage I'm currently using the TrimExcess() method built in to the queue datatype by Microsoft. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=net-6.0)
, this method is inefficient when it comes to large lists and results in a significant time loss whenever it is called.

Is there a more efficient way to remove items from a queue that actually deletes them in RAM aswell?

Edit: to clarify there are still elements in the queue, I just want to remove the elements that have been dequeued from RAM

Comment: `TrimExcess` truncates the internal buffer, if it is lager than the currently used count. It does not remove items. You can empty the queue with `queue.Clear();`.

Comment: This tactic may actually be working against you. 1) `TrimExcess` allocates a new array and moves the items over to it. The original array stays out there until the GC can collect it. It doesn't free the memory immediately. 2) The new array is just big enough for the items in the queue, so if you exceed that new, smaller capacity, it's going to expand the capacity again, which is also as inefficient. The space for a couple thousand entries is not a drain on memory unless you have really large value types in it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no there are still elements in the queue

Comment: Think about how you'd implement a "stretchy" collection like a list or a queue.  You'd need a good backing store (like an array), but you'd need a way for the array to _stretch_. One way to do this is to allocate a reasonably sized array initially.  If you need more space, create a new, bigger array and copy the data from the first array.  Internally, you'd keep track of the current number of items and the size of the array.  As the collection grows, you keep creating/copying-to new arrays, eventually stabilizing at the _high water mark_.  If you trim it, you need to start over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is *"Don't worry about that, and it's very likely that you should not do that."*  This answer is an elaboration of the comments from @madreflection and myself.

The `Queue<T>` class, like other collection classes uses an array to hold the items it collects.  Like other collection classes, if the array runs out of slots, the Queue class creates a new, larger array and copies the data from old array.

I haven't looked at the `Queue<T>` source, but using the debugger, I can see that this array is the `_array` member of the class.  It starts with an array of `0` length.  When you enqueue one item, it gets replaced by an array of length 4.  After that, the array doubles in size whenever it needs more space.

You say your queue *"has a couple thousand entries in it"*.  I'm going to use 2000 in this analysis as a rough guess.

As you enqueue more and more net entries into the queue, that array doubling will happen several times:

| At First | After 5 | After 9 | After 17 | After 33 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 Entries | Double to 8 | Double to 16 | Double to 32 | Double to 64 |

It will keep doing this until it's doubled (and copied the array contents) 10 times - bringing it to 2048.  At that point, you will have allocated 10 arrays, nine of which are garbage, and done about 3000 queued element copies.

Now think about it.  I'm guessing you are enqueue reference type objects.  A reference type object is represented by an object reference (in effect a pointer).  If you have 2000 instances in a queue that will represent 8kb on a 32-bit machine (plus some one-time overhead for the members of the queue class).  On a 64-bit machine, it's 16kb.  That's nothing for a modern computer.  The .NET garbage collector has two strategies for managing memory, a normal one and one for large objects.  The boundary is 85kb; your queue will never be a *large object*

If you are enqueuing large value types, then more memory is needed (since the value type objects will be copied into the array elements that make up the queue entries).  You'd need to be using very large value type objects before your queue becomes a *large object*.

The other thing that will happen is that as your queue grows in size, it will settle into the Garbage Collector's Gen2 memory area.  Gen2 collections are expensive, but once an object becomes stable in Gen2, it doesn't bother the garbage collector at all.

But, think about what happens if you reduce your queue size way down to, say 100 entries and call `TrimExcess`.  At that point, yet another new array will be created (this time, much smaller) and the entries in your queue will be copied to that new queue (that's what the notes in the *Remarks* section of the `TrimExcess` documentation is referring to when it talks about *The cost of reallocating and copying a large `Queue<T>`*).  If your queue starts growing again, you will start doubling/copying that array over and over again - spinning off more garbage and spinning your wheels doing the copying.

A better strategy is to look at your estimated queue size, inflate it a bit, and pre-allocate the space for all of those entries at construction time.  If you expect to have 2000 entries, allocate space for 2500 in the constructor:

```
var myQueue = new Queue<SomeType>(2500);
```

Now, you do one allocation, there should be no reallocation or array copying, and your memory will quickly migrate to Gen2, but will never be touched by the GC.